# Reading row of data from excel

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I need to read rows from my excel and insert it to SQl server. While inserting i ll check whether those rows are existing or not, according to that a flag ll b return to the front end.

So far, i have did a column wise reading. please any one help me to read data row wise from excel, and insert to SQL server in VB.Net

Need to use Data table and data set.
In VB.NET

Public Class Form1

```
'#Region "Decleration"
'Dim exApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
'Dim exSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
'Dim exCell As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
'Dim dataset1 As New DataSet
'Dim rCount As Integer = 0
'Dim cCount As Integer = 0
'Dim objValues As Object
'Dim totalRecords As Integer = 0

'#End Region

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWorkSheets As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ExcelSheetName As String = ""

    '   objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    '   objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Jidh\Desktop\tttttttttttttttttt.xlsx")


End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog_FileOk(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles FileUpload1.FileOk

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub btnChoseDoc_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChoseDoc.Click
    If FileUpload1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try

            Dim DS As DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection

            Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable

            MyConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jidh\Desktop\tttttttttttttttttt.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";")

            MyConnection.Open()

            dtExcelSchema = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
            Dim SheetName As String = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
            MyConnection.Close()

            MyConnection.Open()

            ' Select the data from Sheet1 of the workbook.
            MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" & SheetName & "]", MyConnection)
            DS = New System.Data.DataSet()
            MyCommand.Fill(DS)
            grvRecords.DataSource = DS.Tables(0).DefaultView
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally


        End Try



    End If

End Sub

'Private Sub ReleaseComObject(ByVal obj As Object)
'    Try
'        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objValues)
'        obj = Nothing
'    Catch ex As Exception
'        obj = Nothing
'    Finally
'        GC.Collect()
'    End Try
'End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What code do you have at the moment? No point asking a question and hoping someone does the work for you - show you have at least tried.

Comment: I have tried it, here you check it out

Comment: That's what I meant, show your code so we can help you work through it. Will have a quick look and let you know.

Comment: Okay, I've compiled your code and it seems to run fine. It adds each of the columns, and each of the rows of Sheet1. I haven't made any changes to your code. Can you specify what error you were having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've compiled your code and it seemed to extract all the data from Excel pretty well. Of course, if you don't want the first row of data to be your column headers then you just change the HDR to NO and that will solve that problem. Next, you've asked for it to be put into a dataset, which your code already does. This is then easily transferred to a datatable, and you have that.

Now, the part you asked to have it put into SQL. There are a few different ways. You can either put all the data into an XML document and then have an SQL stored procedure read that and insert it. Next, you can loop through each of the rows in the datatable and add it that way. I've gone with the method I think would be best, basing from MSDN ([MSDN - Bulk Copy Data into SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)).

Let me know how you go.

```
    Public YourDatatableWithExcelData As New System.Data.DataTable

Private Sub btnChoseDoc_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If FileUpload1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try

            Dim DS As DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection

            Dim dtExcelSchema As System.Data.DataTable

            MyConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\dawid\Desktop\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";")

            MyConnection.Open()

            dtExcelSchema = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
            Dim SheetName As String = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
            MyConnection.Close()

            MyConnection.Open()

            ' Select the data from Sheet1 of the workbook.
            MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" & SheetName & "]", MyConnection)
            DS = New System.Data.DataSet()
            MyCommand.Fill(DS)
            grvRecords.DataSource = DS.Tables(0).DefaultView
            YourDatatableWithExcelData = DS.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally


        End Try



    End If

End Sub

Private Sub InsertIntoSQL(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Using destinationConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=servername;" & "Initial Catalog=databasename;" & "User ID=username;" & "Password=userpassword;")

        destinationConnection.Open()

        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection)
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.YourTableNameToCopyDataTo"
            Try
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(YourDatatableWithExcelData)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

We've made a globally declared datatable called `YourDatatableWithExcelData` which is assigned the value of the dataset, and then we call the datatable in the InsertIntoSQL function with the Button2.Click.

Hope this helps.